# How to final publish project in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, publish

I'm done made project... I'm planning to upload to web host... But do i have to upload CakePHP 1.3? then how to set up link to CakePHP 1.3 app folder? or no need? how to make it final without CakePHP 1.3?

Comment: The [Cake installation instructions](http://book.cakephp.org/view/32/Installation) cover this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your cake core folder parallel to your app folder... that's it.

```
public_html/cake
public_html/app
```